# Customize list item

Tags: angular, devextreme

In my Angular application I'm trying to develop a dropdown menu containing a list of checkbox in order to permits multiple selections.

This is my html code:

```
<dx-drop-down-box
    [(value)]="selectedDocTypes"
    displayExpr="label"
    [dataSource]="docTypes">
    <div *dxTemplate="let contentData of 'content'">
        <dx-list 
            selectionMode="multiple"
            [dataSource]="docTypes"
            [showSelectionControls]="true"
            [(selectedItems)]="selectedDocTypes">
        </dx-list>
    </div>
</dx-drop-down-box>
```

With this code the drop download is empty. This is a screenshot of the component:
[image]

As you can see the checkboxes are visible and if I select them the `selectedDocTypes` variable is binded correctly.

Comment: I just followed this demo: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DropDownBox/MultipleSelection/Angular/Light/

Comment: The dataSource (docTypes) is an array of DocumentType. DocumentType is a class with two properties: id and label. I just need to show the label on the right of the checkbox

Comment: A dxList display value is bound to the data source's "text" field. If you do not have this field in your data source, you need to use the item template (https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/List/ListWithSearchBar/Angular/Light/). For example:                                                  
   <dx-list [dataSource]="docTypes>                 
        <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
             <div>{{data.name}}</div>
         </div>                        
   </dx-list>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DxList` component has not option, like `displayExpr`, so to display a complex data you can use an item template.

```
<dx-list
  selectionMode="multiple"
  [dataSource]="docTypes"
  [showSelectionControls]="true"
  [(selectedItemKeys)]="selectedDocTypes">
  <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'item'">
    {{data.label}}
  </div>
</dx-list>
```

Also, I prepared a [plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/darNGwuZIWMdO7F5yRra?p=preview).

PS: You can take a look at [DxTagBox component](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TagBox/Overview/Angular/Light/), it may be more compatible with your scenario.

Comment: Hi Aden, thanks a lot for reply.
I noticed that your code works great only if the array `docTypes` is assigned directly. If you get the value from an Observable, the textbox if filled with  `[object], [object], ...` and not whit the label property.
Try to use this code in the `ngOnInit` method:

`Observable.of([{ id: 1, label: "label1" },{ id: 2, label: "label2" },]).delay(10).subscribe(res => this.docTypes = res);`

Comment: Check [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/41X4ZCdQQL8t06d3OEEI?p=preview). Looks like all work correctly.

Comment: It works now. Passing from DevExtreme 17.1.3 to 17.1.4 does the trik. Do you work in DexExpress? :)
Thanks again